# (django) .update() not working inside class model

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, sql-update

I have the following code but the **.update()** in **remove_user_invite()** isn't working, and no errors are being thrown. Does anyone know what's wrong or how I can fix this? Many Thanks!

**models.py**

```
class StaffProfile(Profile):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, db_index=True, related_name="staff_profiles", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    objects = CustomStaffProfileManager()

    def remove_user_invite(self):
        invites = StaffUserInvite.objects.filter(staff_profile=self, used_at=None, expires_at__gt=timezone.now())
        invites.update(expires_at=timezone.now())
```

Comment: are you sure that `invites` contains any records?

Comment: @AndreyMaslov - Yeah that's how I know it's not working, because when I check admin, the matching records "expires_at" field hasn't changed

Comment: add `print(invites)` before update to be sure that it contains anything and this code is reached by your program)

Comment: @AndreyMaslov - I'm an absolute idiot! Thank you for your help! The call for the function was in the wrong place and so wasn't being called. Thank you so much! Is there anyway to mark a comment as the answer on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have nothing in `invites` or you didn't call this function.
add print(invites) before update to be sure that it contains anything and this code is reached by your program)

Comment: Thanks again for your help! :)